# Comparing proportions from overlapping samples with a complex survey design

Tags: r, survey, proportion, survey-weights, overlapping-data

I am trying to test whether there has been a statistically significant increase in the prevalence of a condition between two years of a complex survey using R. The samples are partly overlapping meaning that there is a longitudinal sample of participants (paired subsample) as well as people only participating in year 1 or only participating in year 2 (unpaired subsamples). Cross-sectional sampling weights are provided for each year. Longitudinal sampling weights may be available. I have identified three potential approaches, outlined below, but I'm unsure about their statistical validity.

**Sample dataset**

Made up data used in the examples below.

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:30),
  subsample = c("Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Both", "yr1only", "yr1only", "yr1only", "yr1only", "yr1only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only", "yr2only"),
  val_yr1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  wt_yr1 = c(689, 379, 695, 26, 426, 538, 708, 507, 96, 990, 543, 753, 986, 405, 879, 936, 501, 194, 530, 417, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  val_yr2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  wt_yr2 = c(91, 305, 995, 854, 396, 782, 175, 971, 193, 857, 480, 828, 792, 694, 920, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 662, 139, 379, 532, 618, 975, 362, 39, 465, 36)
)
```

**Approach 1 – Using bootstrap resampling**

Bootstrap resampling can be carried out using the “withreplicates” function in the “survey” package. Here is my attempt using the sample dataset above.

```
library("survey")

yr1data <- na.omit(data.frame(id = data$id, val = data$val_yr1, wt = data$wt_yr1))
yr1des <- svydesign(id = ~id, weights = ~wt, data = yr1data)
yr1boot <- as.svrepdesign(yr1des, type = "bootstrap", replicates = 1000)
    
yr2data <- na.omit(data.frame(id = data$id, val = data$val_yr2, wt = data$wt_yr2))
yr2des <- svydesign(id = ~id, weights = ~wt, data = yr2data)
yr2boot <- as.svrepdesign(yr2des, type = "bootstrap", replicates = 1000)
    
resultyr1 <- svymean(~val, yr1boot, return.replicates=TRUE)
resultyr2 <- svymean(~val, yr2boot, return.replicates=TRUE)
```

The absolute difference in percentages can be obtained from:

```
resultyr1$mean - resultyr2$mean
```

I generated a 95% confidence interval around the estimate using the bootstrap replicates as follows:

```
quantile(resultyr1[["replicates"]] - resultyr2[["replicates"]], 0.025)
quantile(resultyr1[["replicates"]] - resultyr2[["replicates"]], 0.975)
```

For the p-value my guess would be to use a z-test as follows:

```
z_score <-  as.numeric(resultyr1$mean - resultyr2$mean) / sqrt(var(resultyr1[["replicates"]]) + var(resultyr2[["replicates"]]))
pnorm(z_score)
```

*Does this approach seem correct/appropriate given percentages and partly overlapping samples are involved?*

**Approach 2 – Using Prof. Bland’s method**

Prof. Bland suggested carrying out separate tests for the paired and unpaired subsamples and then taking a weighted combination of the two based on their variance ([https://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mb55/overlap.pdf](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Emb55/overlap.pdf)). This approach looks promising but I am not sure if it can be combined with complex survey methods since the sample needs to be divided into both paired (longitudinal) and unpaired samples.

*What survey weights should be used for the paired sample?*

Thoughts: Longitudinal weights may be available. If no longitudinal weights are provided would it be appropriate to use an average of the two cross-sectional weights i.e. (wt_yr1 + wt_yr2)/2?

*What survey weights should be used for the unpaired samples?*

Thoughts: Are the two sets of cross-sectional weights (i.e. wt_yr1 & wt_yr2) still appropriate when the longitudinal subsample of participants has been removed?

*How best would the variance be calculated in the paired and unpaired subsamples before combining them?*

Thoughts: For calculating the variance of the paired and unpaired subsamples it could be generated using Prof. Bland’s equations and relative survey-weighted counts (i.e. survey-weighted proportion * samples size). Alternatively, maybe the variance could be generated using bootstrap resampling as in Approach 1 above.

**Approach 3 – using method proposed by Derrick et al. (“Partiallyoverlapping” package)**

The package “Partiallyoverlapping” created by Derrick et al. can be used to compare means and proportions between two partly overlapping samples.

*Is there any way of combining this approach with the sampling weights?*

Thoughts: There are two methods for data entry available in this package.

```
# Method 1 for a single stacked dataset.
library("Partiallyoverlapping")
Prop.test(data$val_yr1, data$val_yr2, stacked=TRUE, conf.level=.95)

# Method 2 for separate datasets.
library("Partiallyoverlapping")
paired <- data[ which(data$subsample=="Both"), ]
yr1only <- data[ which(data$subsample=="yr1only"), ]
yr2only <- data[ which(data$subsample=="yr2only"), ]
Prop.test(yr1only$val_yr1, yr2only$val_yr2, paired$val_yr1, paired$val_yr2, stacked = FALSE, conf.level=.95)
```